# When using FileUpload for multiple files, the image names are correct but they are all the same color

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, webforms

I'm uploading images using the FileUploadControl to my database, then to make sure that it worked I print out the images info and then ouput the images to the screen. 
For some reason that I can't figure out is why the images I am using stay the same color but with different names. I.E

1.png is Red, 2.png is Green, 3.png is blue and 4.png is yellow.

But when I call out the images that were uploaded to the database it now goes as this..

1.png is Red, 2.png is Red, 3.png is Red and 4.png is Red

I have stepped through the code and it seems normal, I have looked at the Markup after it is ran and the image names are all correct. But when I look in the folder it is as I mentioned all the same color as 1.png.

The FileUpload

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Making sure that images are images
        string[] matchExtension = { ".jpg", ".png", ".gif" };
        string[] matchMimeType = { "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif" };

        if (fpSlideshow.HasFiles)
        {
            string imgName;
            string imgExtension;
            string imgMime;

            foreach (HttpPostedFile upLoadedFile in fpSlideshow.PostedFiles)
            {
                imgName = upLoadedFile.FileName;
                imgExtension = Path.GetExtension(imgName);
                imgMime = fpSlideshow.PostedFile.ContentType;

                if (matchExtension.Contains(imgExtension) && matchMimeType.Contains(imgMime))
                {
                    fpSlideshow.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"~/SlideshowImages/" + imgName));
                    string thePath = Server.MapPath(@"~/SlideshowImages/" + imgName).ToString();

                    daccess.AddImagesToSlideshow(imgName, imgExtension, imgMime, thePath);
                }
            }
        }
        daccess.GetImageNames();
        CreateMyStuff();

        for (int i = 0; i != daccess.dsTEST.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Response.Write("<br>" + daccess.dsTEST.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ImageName"].ToString() + "<br>" +
                daccess.dsTEST.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ImageType"].ToString() + "<br>" +
                daccess.dsTEST.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ImageMime"].ToString() + "<br>" +
                daccess.dsTEST.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ImageUrl"].ToString() + "<br>");
        }
    }
```

The CreateMyStuff method

```
private void CreateMyStuff()
    {

        // Current row count.
        int rowCtr;

        // Total number of cells per row (columns).
        int cellCtr;

        //count number of rows in dataset
        int rN = daccess.dsTEST.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

        for (rowCtr = 0; rowCtr < rN; rowCtr++)
        {
            // Create a new row and add it to the table.
            TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
            Table1.Rows.Add(tRow);

            for (cellCtr = 1; cellCtr <= 2; cellCtr++)
            {
                //
                Button button = new Button();
                //
                HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
                // Create a new cell and add it to the row.
                TableCell tCell = new TableCell();

                if (rowCtr == rN)
                    break;

                string myName = daccess.dsTEST.Tables[0].Rows[rowCtr]["ImageName"].ToString();

                StringBuilder myStrBldr = new StringBuilder();

                myStrBldr.Append("<div class=''>");
                myStrBldr.Append("<img src='SlideshowImages/" + myName + "' />");
                myStrBldr.Append("</div>");


                tCell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(myStrBldr.ToString()));

                tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
                rowCtr++;

                if (cellCtr == 2)
                {
                    rowCtr = rowCtr - 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Its obvious that its happening in the upload control, but I am not seeing where my mistake is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This call :

```
fpSlideshow.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"~/SlideshowImages/" + imgName));
```

doesn't seem to have any dependence on `uploadedFile`.  It's the same method being called on the same object with a different filename for the saved file each time.  If `fpSlideshow` is an instance of the `FileUpload` class then I think the default behaviour is to save the first file in `PostedFiles`.  Calling `.SaveAs` on the `uploadedFile` should correct the issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I changed the fpSlideshow to uploadedFile and it works perfectly now.